# Loading namespace symbols inside a function for a template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, boost, namespaces, boost-range

I have written a templacised `operator+=` function and given it a unique namespace (I only want to use it sometimes, and this allows me to exlpicitly).

I would like to then use *that* function inside another template function that uses `operator+=` on its operands, but I don't want to leave it hanging around in the symbol table waiting to pounce on every single `+=` call I do anywhere in my program. I also have to do this inside a header that is widely included.

A basic example of this is:

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE

#include "boost\range.hpp"
#include "boost\range\algorithm.hpp"
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

namespace range_ops
{
    template <class ForwardRange1, class SinglePassRange2>
    inline ForwardRange1& operator+=(ForwardRange1& left, const SinglePassRange2& right)
    {
        auto left_it = boost::begin(left);
        auto right_it = boost::begin(right);
        for (; left_it != boost::end(left); ++left_it, ++right_it)
            *left_it += *right_it;

        return left;
    }
}

template <class SinglePassRange, class Value>
inline Value accumulate_increment(SinglePassRange& rng, Value val)
{
    typedef typename boost::range_value<SinglePassRange>::type range_val;
    boost::for_each(rng, [&](const range_val& x) { val += x; });
    return val;
}

template <class SinglePassRange>
inline typename boost::range_value<SinglePassRange>::type accumulate_increment(SinglePassRange& rng)
{
    return accumulate_increment(rng, typename boost::range_value<SinglePassRange>::type());
}

//using range_ops::operator+=; // this works, but pollutes the global namespace with a templacised operator+= function - yuck!
int main()
{
    auto i = accumulate_increment(vector<int>(1)); // works fine

    using range_ops::operator+=; // want this here, but accumulate_increment can't see the operator+= function
    auto j = accumulate_increment(vector<vector<int>>(1));
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

There is only 1 increment function so how did you expect you using clause in the caller to affect the increment function itself - how is it supposed to find operatior+?

Comment: Because template functions are only instantiated at the call site, so you only need the function to be visible at the point you first call it. The trouble is, template functions are instantiated at the start of the function that calls them, not at the actual line where they are first used. Hence, using declarations inside the function itself are not considered when the template function is being instantiated.

Comment: Ayjay - you should post that as the answer - rather than my weak reply

Comment: Hah it's not an answer, it's a description as to why it is hard. I'm trying to ask if there is a way around that!

Comment: I do not get what you are trying to do - the operator+'s take 2 classes. Can you give a better real world example to maybe see what you are really trying to do

Comment: Basically, I have written a template function that allows range increment. eg. `vector<int> x, y; x += y;` This is a completely generic function, and can take anything that models Boost's `range` concept. Because of how generic it is, I don't like having it hanging around in the symbol table, so I have wrapped it up in a `range_ops` namespace. I have also written a custom `accumulate`-like function that operates off `operator+=`, simply because that is almost always how I use it. I am now trying to use the two in combination.

Comment: I still do not understand the total problem - can you provide a complete example where a) It calls you operator+() as expected and b) calls your operator+() when you did not want it too. Generally never ever worry about optimization unless you can prove it is a problem.

Comment: Check the question again now - it's been updated with basically the exact code I have in my solution, and the way I use it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could do this I would not recommend it.  Someone using your code should expect an object's internal behavior to not depend on some external state (your setting of the namespace) that is not explicitly passed into it and doesn't move around with it (not something that depends on where is it geographically sitting in a source file).

Operator overloading is already a feature that borders on making things confusing except in cases where the operands are things that normally would not support that operator in nature.

If you were to implement something like this, you should do it by setting state of the object that changes the behavior of the operator you overload, such as a member SetOtherOperatorOverload(TRUE);